# Why using my subdomain URL displays insecure HTTPS and not my normal domain URL?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

My website's hosted on Hostinger, and my subdomain is configured to point to a single-page website in my subfolder **public_html/me**. However, if I type **me.mydomain.com**, in the browser, the lock displays as if my site is insecure. In the other hand, if I type in my browser https://www.mydomain .com/me, it's fine.

My SSL certificate is active and spreads across all my subdomains.

Another weird thing is, if I type https://me.mydomain.com, I get an SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT.

Root .htaccess looks like:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW SSL_REDIRECT:mydomain.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain.com
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW SSL_REDIRECT:mydomain.com
```

There is no .htaccess in my subfolder.
Can you help me solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've got my answer from tech support of my hoster. It's because unlike what I believed, the certificate does not apply to my subdomains. I've bought extra certificates and installed them on my subdomains individually and now all works fine.